# Difference between ArrayList declarations

Tags: java, arrays, list, generics, arraylist

I was reading online and I saw a declaration for an `ArrayList` as

```
ArrayList[] graph = new ArrayList[numCourses];
```

Traditionally, I thought that `ArrayList`s were always declared as

```
ArrayList<type> graph = new ArrayList<type>();
```

What's the difference between these two? The rest of the code seemed to utilize the same functions from the `ArrayList` class, but with specific indices.

Comment: The first one declares an array of raw `ArrayLists`: the second one declares a single `ArrayList<type>`.

Comment: @VishwaRatna He asked for the difference between the two declarations in the question. No thinking required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ArrayList[]` declares an array of `ArrayList` objects. `graph` is then initialized with an array of length `numCourses`.

While `ArrayList[]` uses the [raw type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it) `ArrayList`, `ArrayList<type> graph` uses the generic type `ArrayList<T>` and passes `type` as the type argument.

These two are not interchangeable. An array cannot be used instead of its component type. `ArrayList[]` is probably being used to circumvent the limitation that prevents the instantiation of arrays of generic types.

Answer (score 1):

From [Oracle: Cannot Create Arrays of Parameterized Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html#createArrays)

> You cannot create arrays of parameterized types. For example, the following code does not compile:
>
> `List<Integer>[] arrayOfLists = new List<Integer>[2];  // compile-time error`

So yeah you are right only correct way to declare List or collection in general is like below:

```
ArrayList<type> graph = new ArrayList<type>();
```

Answer (score 1):

With brackets (`[]`) an array is created, whereas with "beaks" (`<>`) parameter type is passed.

Your second line creates an `ArrayList` of type `type`, whereas the first line creates an array of raw `ArrayList`s (with no type) - those are whole different objects.

If you want a collection of parametrized `List`s, array is not the way to go. Better use nested lists: `List<List<type>>`.